# Why is 11 Dimensional SUGRA not a consistent quantum theory?

Tags: string-theory, renormalization, dimensional-analysis, supergravity

I am studying the $S$ duality between 11D supergravity and type IIA superstring theory from Adel Bilal’s [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9710136). The author says:

> Of course, eleven dimensional supergravity is not expected to yield a consistent quantum theory. It should only be the low-energy limit of some consistent theory, baptised M-theory.

I don’t understand what this really means. What is a “consistent quantum theory”? And how do we know that 11 dimensional supergravity is the low energy limit of M theory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially the answer is that **the eleven dimensional supergravity is non-renormalizable**; to be precise, above two loops, the graviton-graviton scattering amplitude is divergent. A nice review on the specifics of maximal supergravity is [Kaluza-Klein supergravity](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370157386901638?via%3Dihub).

Some comments to gain intuition about the UV problems in eleven dimensional supergravity:

1. They only known way to avoid the UV divergences in all known consistent theories of gravity is the UV/IR mixing mechanism of string theory amplitudes (see my answer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69981/is-string-theory-proven-to-be-finite) question). Such a mechanism is absent in the maximal supergravity.
2. Non-perturbative states in its spectrum exist, namely membranes, [three-branes](https://inspirehep.net/literature/449319) and fivebranes. It is known that the worldvolume theory of the M5-brane is always strongly coupled (the moduli space of its parameters is just a point). A consequence of this is that there is no possibilty to derive its physics from a lagrangian theory, in particular not from the lagrangian of the maximal supergravity. Something more is needed.
3. As in any supergravity, it's not clear that a lagrangian description must be the correct description of the theory at the Planck scale. Again, an unknown UV-regulator (new physics) is needed.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. My undergrad thesis involves reproducing the Becker sisters' calculation (which uses the Matrix model of M theory) to compute the scattering of D0 branes at two loops and comparing it the result to 11D supergravity.

Comment: It's always a real pleasure. It sounds like a truly wonderful undergraduate thesis, a really nice training on important stuff. Stay curious, and the best of all lucks for your project.